# Jenkins build from command line with dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-cli

First of all, apologies if this question seems stupid. I have been given a task to automate jenkins build for maven projects and i do not have good knowledge on jenkins.

After going through some links, i found using jenkins-cli will be good fit for my requirement.
I could build project a repository using jenkins-cli. However, each maven project may dependent on other internal projects and i need to build after building all those dependent projects first.

Could you please suggest me a way to build project after building dependencies.?

Answer (score 0):

So what you basically have is a build pipeline. This can all be handled by Jenkins.

Start out with the Job definition for each project and then define the which projects should be built after successful completion. Have a look at [this](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/05/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and.html) detailed description.

Furthermore, I do not think that you even have to bother with the command line interface, as you can define build triggers (e.g. periodically, after a commit). See [this](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-poll) concise description for a Git SCM, but should work similarly for other source control repositories.